# AngularJS: Passing VM Variable in Controller to Another Ajax Call

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ajax, virtual-machine

I am currently trying to figure out away to return an ID from my first AJAX call and pass that ID into the second AJAX call. I have set `let vm = this`. What is the correct way to pass `vm.data.id` from `results.id` into the second call?

```
      vm.retrieveId = () => {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                url: url,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (res) {
                    vm.data = res;
                    console.log(vm.data);
                }
            });

        };

        vm.getPhotos = () => {
            $.ajax
            ({
                type: "GET",
                url: "http://webbtelescope.org/api/v3/image/" + vm.data.id,
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                success: function (res) {
                    let results = res;
                    vm.photos = results;

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: What currently happens when you pass in `vm.data.id` with the current method?

Comment: It is undefined @BShaps

Comment: If you are for sure calling `vm.retrieveId()` before calling `vm.getPhotos()` I would consider trying to see if it is a scope issue.  You can check that by changing `vm.data = res` to `vm.data = angular.copy(res)`

Comment: I was actually able to pass it in by using lodash's _.map() function. Although, I know have an array of ID's that I need to figure out how to iterate through for multiple ajax calls.

Comment: I don't know how your code operates, but if you are sending through multiple ajax calls all at once, you can use angularjs' `$http.get` and push the calls into an array so you can do a `$q.all()` and know the order of the results will be the same as the order they were passed into the array

Comment: @BShaps Unfortunately, I cannot use $http.get  with this API, due to a CORS issue. AJAX is really my only option.

Comment: @StephenRoss That's unlikely because $http is supposed to be drop-in replacement for $.ajax, hence the question is likely XY problem. If JSONP is the issue then there's $http.jsonp. Consider providing the details that explain what's the problem. You can use promises/deferreds with $.ajax (actually, you should) to maintain proper control flow but this is still hacky and weird way since $http is there.

Comment: @estus if i use `vm.retrieveId = () => {
            $http.get('http://webbtelescope.org/api/v3/images/all?page=1').then(function (res) {
                vm.items = mapID(res);
                console.log(vm.data);
            }, function (error) {
                console.log(error);
            });
        };` I receive a CORS error. Not sure how to get around it.

Comment: As I mentioned, the counterpart to $.ajax `dataType: 'jsonp'` is `$http.jsonp`, not `$http.get`.